# How do I display the correct view based on the model's "type"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a database that is set up using EF Table Per Type, and I am trying to write a details View in Razor for the details page. The tricky part is that I have a base class `Product` and two derived classes `VideoProduct` and `DatabaseProduct`, and I want to display them all in a list View and be able to provide a details View for each type. I am having trouble figuring out how to determine which View to return depending on the type of object that comes back from the database. Here is some of the code:

**MODELS:**

```
public abstract class Product
{
    // some properties
}

public class DatabaseProduct
{
    int SpecialInvoiceID { get; set; }
}

public class VideoProduct
{
    public virtual ICollection<FilmsCollection> FilmsCollectionIDs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OtherCollection> OtherCollectionIDs { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var product = db.Products.Find(id); // could be a VideoProduct or a DatabaseProduct

    if (product == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View("Details", product);
}
```

**VIEW:**

What do I do here to allow the details View to display either type of Model? Or what can I do in the Controller to call different Views to display for different Model Classes? Or can I use DisplayForModel?

I tried to find an example of this through Google, but I wasn't able to get any useful information. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the [Queryable.OfType(TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) extension method in order to filter the entities of type DatabaseProduct or VideoProduct. Look at this sample code

```
DatabaseProduct dbp = (from d in db.Products.OfType<DatabaseProduct>()
                       where d.Id == id
                       select d.FirstOrDefault();
```

This kind of query will filter the entities of a certain type and so you can act accordingly when you build the list of products (for example redirecting the user to two different details action or something like that)

Have a look [here](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-3.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I ended up using DisplayForModel, but this is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Display/Editor Templatesfeature described here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var product = db.Products.Find(id); // could be a VideoProduct or a DatabaseProduct

    if (product == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View(product.GetType().Name, product);
}
```